# Bounding sum of samples of a Gaussian

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, fourier-analysis, approximation-theory

Suppose we have $K$ points $x_1,\ldots,x_K$ in $\mathbb{R}^d$ and let
 $$f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^K \exp(-\lambda \Vert x-x_k \rVert^2).$$
Can we uniformly bound $f$ independent of $K$?

It is okay to use some assumption on the distribution of $\{x_k\}$.